# Grouping exploded data by its unique value

Tags: php

I have text list that values are seperated by tabs like this: (x.dat)

```
9  2
9   3
9   20
9   16
9   8
14  35
14  17
```

I want printed it out like this:

```
9  2   3   20  16  8
14  35  17
```

```
$file=file_get_contents("x.dat");
$rows=array_map('trim',explode("\n",$file));

foreach($rows as $row){
    $c=explode("\t",$row);
    echo $c[1]."\t";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in this way, [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8b537a51d5de081c678dbe2185c2cc186e4c64d4)

```
$array = explode("\n",$string);
foreach($array as $value){
    $arr = explode("\t",$value);
    $result[$arr[0]][] = $arr[1];
}


foreach($result as $k => $v){
    echo "$k\t" . join("\t",$v) . "\n";
}
```

---

```
/*   unique in order
foreach($result as $k => $v){
    $v[] = $k;
    array_unique($v);
    sort($v);
    echo join("\t",$v) . "\n";
}
*/
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks. Can i remove the duplicate $v values for each line? And additionally is it possible to sort them by ascending?

Comment: @OzzyChigurh check the content I added.

Comment: After changing "$v[] = $k; array_unique($v);" with "$v2 = array_unique($v);" it's ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've hardcoded the values for testing, but this seems to work. I've also run out of time to print out the values in the format you want, but that shouldn't be too hard. The last line shows the values in 2 arrays with indexes of 9 and 14. You just need to loop through that to get your results.

I used http://phptester.net/ to write this.

```
$file = "9\t2
9\t3
9\t20
9\t16
9\t8
14\t35
14\t17";

$rows = array_map('trim', explode("\n", $file));
$result = [];

foreach($rows as $row){
    $c = explode("\t", $row);

    if (!isset($result[$c[0]])){
        $result[$c[0]] = [$c[1]];
    }
    else {
        array_push($result[$c[0]], $c[1]);
    }
}
print_r($result);
```